# How can I send the content of the file to HTTP Event Collector in Splunk?

Tags: http, events, splunk, collectors

I am using a script that gives me some data in json format, I want to send this data to splunk.
I can store the output of the script in a file but how can I send it to HTTP Event Collector?

Couple of things I tried but did not work:

---

```
FILE="output.json"
file1="cat answer.txt"
curl -k "https://prd-pxxx.splunkcloud.com:8088/services/collector"  -H "Authorization: Splunk XXXXX"  -d  '{"event": "$file1", "sourcetype": "manual"}'

-----------------------------------------------------------
```

curl -k "https://prd-pxxx.splunkcloud.com:8088/services/collector"  -H "Authorization: Splunk XXXXX"  -d  '{"event": "@output.json", "sourcetype": "manual"}'

---

```
curl -k "https://prd-p-w0gjo.splunkcloud.com:8088/services/collector"  -H "Authorization: Splunk d70b305e-01ef-490d-a6d8-b875d98e689b"   -d '{"sourcetype":"_json", "event": "@output.json", "source": "output.json}

-----------------------------------------------------------------

After trying this I understand that it literally sends everything specified in the event section. Is there a way I can send the content of the file or use a variable? 

Thanks in advance!
```

Answer (score 0):

(Note - I haven't tried this specifically, but it should get you close)

---

According to [Docs.Splunk on HTTP Event Collector Examples #3](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/HECExamples#Example_3:_Send_raw_text_to_HEC), it would seem you can do something very similar to this:

```
curl -k "https://mysplunkserver.example.com:8088/services/collector/raw?channel=00872DC6-AC83-4EDE-8AFE-8413C3825C4C&sourcetype=splunkd_access&index=main" \
    -H "Authorization: Splunk CF179AE4-3C99-45F5-A7CC-3284AA91CF67" \
    -d < $FILE
```

Presuming the content of the file is formatted correctly, it *should* go straight in.

How is the file being created? Is it in a Deployment App on a managed endpoint? If so, it will *likely* be simpler to setup a [scripted input](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/AdvancedDev/ScriptSetup) for the UF to run on whatever schedule you choose.